# Emulating is_pointer with gcc version 4.1.2

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I was wondering if it possible to emulate the boost, tr1 is_pointer functionality on gcc 4.1.2 on Centos version 5.5. If it is possible, I would welcome suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: does it not work to just use the boost library itself?

Comment: @Tristan , We have experimenting with the boost library , particularly the boost regex class. We are still evaluating it. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The trick is in specialisation:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer {
   enum { value = 0 };
};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer<T*> {
   enum { value = 1 };
};

template <typename T>
bool ptr_test(const T&) {
   return is_pointer<T>::value;
}

int main() {
   int *ptr;
   const int *ptr2;
   int a;
   double b;

   std::cout << "ptr:" << ptr_test(ptr) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ptr2:" << ptr_test(ptr2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "a:" << ptr_test(a) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "b:" << ptr_test(b) << std::endl;

}
```

(Works as expected on CentOS 5.3, with gcc 4.1.2)

Comment: `ptr_test()` should be `inline` IMHO. Yes, yes, I know that compiller will probably optimize it without it, but still, it should be there.

Comment: I only put ptr_test() in to show how type deduction could be useful.

Comment: @Pawel: The `inline` keyword has very little to nothing to do with actual inlining. Not only that, but templates by nature are nearly implicitly inline anyway. Using `inline` here is just noise, only use it when you need to break the one-definition rule.

Comment: @GMan: yes, I know that this is just a suggestion to a compiler, not an order, but still IMO it should be there.

Comment: @Pawel: Okay, but on what basis do you hold your opinion? In my opinion, it shouldn't be there...so what? We can list opinions all day, it's the ones that are reasonable that we should hold on to and suggest. And it's not reasonable to think `inline` is changing anything here, so its just noise. (And furthermore, I think it's reasonable to avoid noise, so we should avoid `inline`, here.)

Comment: @Gman: It should be there because it shows your intention and not making anything worse. It's noice in your opinion, it's not in my opinion.